# iOS - Background view is consuming touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uikit

I'll start by describing how the screen looks. It is a `UIPageViewController` that covers 100% of the screen and a `UIView` **(on top of the page vc)** that covers 20% of the screen. Easy, right? basically `UIView` is over `UIPageViewController`.

So, I'm adding said `UIPageViewController` programatically to my view controller with `self.view.addSubview(pageVC.view)`. but the `UIView` is defined in the **interface builder**

For this reason, since the `UIPageViewController` is added last it covers the `UIView` which forced me to call `myUIView.layer.zPosition = 1` so that the `UIView` is visible.

The problem is any touch made on the `UIView` is instead consumed by the `UIPageViewController`. how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using [`view.insertSubview(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview:belowSubview:) instead? Or using [`bringSubviewToFront`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:), or [`sendSubviewToBack`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sendSubviewToBack:)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layer property of a particular view is only used for the rendering of that specific view. That's the reason why changes to the layer won't impact anything regarding the interaction with that specific view.

However, the `-sendSubviewToBack:` and `-bringSubviewToFront:` methods on UIView were designed to achieve exactly what you are looking for. Here you can read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:) for them.

I wrote this piece of code so that you can test what this method is doing. Try to comment/uncomment the last line or changing the order in which the subviews are added to get a better understanding of how it works.

```
UIView *firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
UIView *secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 150, 150)];

firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:firstView];
[self.view addSubview:secondView];

UITapGestureRecognizer *firstTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(firstTap)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *secondTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(secondTap)];
[firstView addGestureRecognizer:firstTap];
[secondView addGestureRecognizer:secondTap];

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:secondView];
```